# One Add to Cart Buttoon on Category page using Woocommerce

Tags: customization, woocommerce

I have a client that wants a quantity box with each product on the category shop page, but only have one add to cart button either at the top or bottom, so that people can tab across with quantities and then hit the add to cart button only once. I have searched for days to no avail. Anyone that has an idea I would be eternally grateful.

thanks in advance